# Building Eclipse plugins with Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, gradle

Is there any Gradle tutorial or plugin that shows how to build/distribute Eclipse plugins with the help of Gradle build?

Somethig similar to Tycho project for Maven: http://eclipse.org/tycho/ ?

Comment: Are there any options for this that work with recent versions of eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of the existence of a plugin comparable to Tycho. See [this Gradle forum entry](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/is_it_possible_to_build_an_eclipse_plugin) for a related discussion.

Answer (score 15):

I published today new gradle plugin - Wuff version 0.0.1, that allows you to fully automate build/distribution of Eclipse plugins and applications.

Full source code and docs here: https://github.com/akhikhl/wuff

Plugin artifacts are available at jcenter and maven central!

Comment: Does this work together with buildship as well? https://projects.eclipse.org/proposals/eclipse-plug-ins-gradle

Comment: To my best knowledge and to current date (2015-03-12) buildship is not yet available.
I will certainly consider harmonic integration with buildship, as soon as it's sources and APIs are available.

Comment: Looking forward to it. It was just presented at EclipseCon, and Gradleware seems to be pretty serious about it.

Comment: This doesn't work at all due to a fatal error, and a pull request which fixes this issue is left abandoned.

Comment: Check out Goomph. It is actively maintained and used to build some of Eclipse's own projects. I think gitpod uses it as well.