# Using Wuff (Gradle Plugin) to Build Eclipse Plugins

Tags: eclipse, gradle, build.gradle

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952641/building-eclipse-plugins-with-gradle/23475617), I stared looking at Wuff to help with a Gradle build (converting an Eclipse plugin).
This is probably such a newbie question, so I do apologize in advance, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere:

We're currently using Eclipse 4.3.1. So, I followed the [wiki page](https://github.com/akhikhl/wuff/wiki/Configuration-DSL) and changed the version:

```
wuff{
  selectedEclipseVersion = '4.3.1'
  eclipseVersion('4.3.1') {
 }
}
```

Which seems to work. However, the default mirror site does not contain that version anymore, so I'm a fileNotFoundException error (for eclipse-SDK-4.3.1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz).

Now, I'm guessing it should have automatically gone to the archive site, but for some reason it does not.
I tried fiddling around with the eclipseMirror extension (since changing extra properties is now disabled by Gradle):

```
wuff.ext.'eclipseMirror' = 'http://archive.eclipse.org'
```

but to no avail.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I just found [this](https://github.com/akhikhl/wuff/blob/master/libs/wuff-plugin/src/main/resources/org/akhikhl/wuff/defaultConfig.groovy), so I guess I'll be fine, but I'll keep the question around for others to use if needed.

Comment: `wuff.ext.eclipseMirror` is still setting an extra property. Perhaps you want `wuff.eclipseMirror`. Also, changing extra properties isn't disabled. What happened is that dynamic properties were removed in favor of extra properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same version name just overrides the exiting properties, it does not delete the rest, which was the problem (thanks to Andrey Hihlovskiy for pointing it out!). I wrote the following workaround:

```
selectedEclipseVersion = '4.3.1-mine'
...
eclipseVersion('4.3.1-mine'){
extendsFrom '4.2.2'
eclipseMavenGroup = 'eclipse-kepler-sr1' 
eclipseMirror = 'http://mirror.netcologne.de'
eclipseArchiveMirror = 'http://archive.eclipse.org'
def suffix_os = [ 'linux': 'linux-gtk', 'macosx': 'macosx-cocoa', 'windows': 'win32' ]
def suffix_arch = [ 'x86_32': '', 'x86_64': '-x86_64' ]
def fileExt_os = [ 'linux': 'tar.gz', 'macosx': 'tar.gz', 'windows': 'zip' ]

def current_os = //your os
def current_arch = //your arch

sources {
    source "$eclipseMirror/eclipse//technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR1/eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-${suffix_os[current_os]}${suffix_arch[current_arch]}.${fileExt_os[current_os]}"
    source "$eclipseMirror/eclipse//technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR1/eclipse-rcp-kepler-SR1-${suffix_os[current_os]}${suffix_arch[current_arch]}.${fileExt_os[current_os]}", sourcesOnly: true
    languagePackTemplate '${eclipseMirror}/eclipse//technology/babel/babel_language_packs/R0.11.1/kepler/BabelLanguagePack-eclipse-${language}_4.3.0.v20131123020001.zip'
}
```